# Delete edges (to make it oriented) preserving the strongly connected property

Tags: graphs, data-structures

*A directed graph is said to be oriented if for all edges (i, j), (j, i) is not an edge. In other words, the binary relation defined by the edges is asymmetric. Given a strongly connected directed graph, you have to find whether there exists a spanning oriented subgraph which is also strongly connected. In other words, if for some nodes i,j, both (i, j) and (j, i) are edged in the graph, you have to delete at least one of the two edges, preserving the strongly connected property of the graph. If there is no such subgraph, print “impossible” else print “possible”. If it is possible, print out the edges in any such subgraph, one per line, in any order.*

Credits: A homework problem from my college curriculum

My approach: We can do a DFS and if there's both the path (i, j) & (j, i), one of them will be the tree edge and the other will either be a forward or a backward edge. If the forward edge, we can delete it, if not then we'll have to delete either the tree edge or the back edge. How do I figure out which one to delete?

Comment: Please credit the original source of this problem.  We require you to provide a proper reference for all copied material.

Comment: We're not looking for questions that are just the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Sorry for that, I've added what my approach is but I am unable to figure out the last part.